# Loading Firebase SDKs via reserved URL is giving "Permission denied" error

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have managed to deploy my Firebase site using a reserved url as described in the documentation. Everything works when my database rules are set to "true" however as soon as I try to put in a rule it throws an error "Permission Denied"

I haven't changed the default code for index.html except adding simple lines to try and to include the path of the node I am trying to read or write to. I have managed to use these rules in NodeJS and also in the FirebaseUI for logins through another site but I can't seem to load my sdk config automatically as it suggests in the documentation. Can anyone offer some insight? Thanks.

EDIT: I just successfully attempted to create a new user using firebase.auth(). Obviously my configuration has in fact therefore been automatically imported. I am at a loss as to why I am unable to read or write to the database except as a user within the scope of the rules. I thought the Admin SDK overrides all db rules. Am I missing something obvious?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

  <!-- update the version number as needed -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.21.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.21.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.21.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.21.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <!--script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.js"></script-->
  <!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->

  <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

  <style media="screen">
    body {
      background: #ECEFF1;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
      font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #message {
      background: white;
      max-width: 360px;
      margin: 100px auto 16px;
      padding: 32px 24px;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }

    #message h2 {
      color: #ffa100;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 0 0 8px;
    }

    #message h1 {
      font-size: 22px;
      font-weight: 300;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      margin: 0 0 16px;
    }

    #message p {
      line-height: 140%;
      margin: 16px 0 24px;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    #message a {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      background: #039be5;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }

    #message,
    #message a {
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    }

    #load {
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 13px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 600px) {

      body,
      #message {
        margin-top: 0;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: none;
      }

      body {
        border-top: 16px solid #ffa100;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <div id="message">
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <h1>Firebase Hosting Setup Complete</h1>
    <p>You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something
      extraordinary!</p>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/">Open Hosting Documentation</a>
  </div>
  <p id="load">Firebase SDK Loading&hellip;</p>

  <script>


    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

      firebase.database().ref('/test').set('just a test')

      // // 
      // // The Firebase SDK is initialized and available here!
      //
      // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { });
                 firebase.database().ref('/users').on('value', snapshot => { 
         console.log(snapshot.val())
         console.log(snapshot.key)});
      // firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(() => { });
      // firebase.storage().ref('/path/to/ref').getDownloadURL().then(() => { });
      //
      // // 

      try {
        let app = firebase.app();
        let features = ['auth', 'database', 'messaging', 'storage'].filter(feature => typeof app[feature] === 'function');
        document.getElementById('load').innerHTML = `Firebase SDK loaded with ${features.join(', ')}`;
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        document.getElementById('load').innerHTML = 'Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console.';
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
/*
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
*/

{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      },
      "Google_logins": {
        ".read":true,
        ".write":true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web page is not using the Admin SDK, but the regular JavaScript SDK. This means your code has to adhere to your own security rules and this line:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users').on('value', snapshot => {
```

Won't work, since your security rules don't give anyone permission to read the `/users` node.

If you want the user to read their own node from the database, that'd be:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { 
  if (user) {
    firebase.database().ref('/users').child(user.uid).on('value', snapshot => { 
      ...
```

Comment: I would like to take a snapshot of some secure admin nodes when running my script. Do I have to log myself in as an owner and add this to the rules or Is there a way to use the admin sdk from within the html?

Comment: The Admin SDK can only be used in trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions. It cannot be used in an HTML+JavaScript page. There is no way to be an "owner" in the regular JavaScript SDK. All access from that SDK will have to adhere to the security rules that you configured.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I feel somewhat silly now. I just found it odd that I am able to do so much with firebase.auth() with regard to users yet I can't access the database. I am still very new to all this in general and being a new hobby/career change at 52 I am not exactly picking it up quickly  :)

Comment: Hi Frank, I already tried but because I am new to the forum, the system wont let me vote. It says I need 15 reputations. Thanks again. much appreceated.

Comment: Yeah, that's indeed a requirement. You can still accept the answer if it answered your question though.